# What's a word to describe how someone talks differently to someone who's disabled?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if Person A is talking to someone who is differently abled (Person B), they may do something like attempt to give reasons to Person B why being differently abled has its benefits to make them feel special, even if Person B doesn't need the reassurance. I feel like there is a better word than "condescending" or "patronizing," since in a situation like this, there was no malicious intent.

Comment: It's empathising / using positive discrimination if there's really no condescension / patronising.

Comment: Ignorant. Unless Person A has the same or similar disability as Person B, or a lot of experience with people who do, he doesn't know what he is talking about

Comment: there really should be a word or term for types of "over-compensating" or premature familiarity .. and some related things.

Comment: Perhaps they are ***coddling*** them a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person is talking and acting ***officiously***.  From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/officiously):

> officiously -- in an officious manner.
>
> Officious
>
> Marked by excessive eagerness in offering unwanted services or advice
>   to others: an officious host; officious attention

The OP specifies that Person A is offering reassurance to Person B "even if Person B doesn't need the reassurance."  The OP also specifies that this is done "with no malicious intent."

Person A will claim that he is "just trying to make Person B feel good" or "just trying to help"; what he is actually doing is insisting that he knows better than Person A does what Person A needs and wants.  He is treating Person A like a child.  This may be totally without malice, but it is officious.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the question of how to describe "one who talks differently to someone who is disabled"...to explain.."why being differently abled has its benefits to make them feel special"

***insensitive***

> Showing or feeling no concern for others' feelings.
>   ‘an insensitive remark’
>   [-Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insensitive)

Going even further would be...

***indifferent***

> 3b :  marked by a lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern for something :  apathetic indifferent to suffering and poverty
>   [-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifferent)

Normally, during **empathy training**, we explain the concept in terms of "walking in another person´s shoes"; however, when the other person cannot even walk...the metaphor is useless.

Comment: That's pretty harsh! They might be well-intentioned but misguided. Unfortunately it looks equally bad from the disabled person's point of view, because words don't stop hurting just because they weren't meant to.

Answer (score 1):

> **Infantilize**
> [in-fuh n-tl-ahyz, -tahy-lahyz, in-fan-tl-ahyz]
> /verb (used with object), infantilized, infantilizing.
>
> 1. to keep in or reduce to an infantile state.
> 2. to treat or regard as infantile or immature.

If your intention is to demonstrate that Person B is reducing the integrity of Person A this might be a good term. It implies that Person B believes that Person A needs their additional support because the condition diminishes them to less than a capable person and therefore they need extra caring for.

Comment: This is probably the runner-up for the answer. Will definitely use it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone does this a little bit while talking to different people.

Consciously or not you always [***tailor***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tailor) your conversation depending on who you talk to.

> Make or adapt for a particular purpose or person.
>   *‘arrangements can be tailored to meet individual requirements’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tailor

Answer (score 0):

> **Pity**
> [pit-ee]/
> noun, plural pities.
>
> 1. sympathetic or kindly sorrow evoked by the suffering, distress, or misfortune of another, often leading one to give relief or aid or to show mercy.
> 2. a cause or reason for pity, sorrow, or regret.
>
> /adjective
>
> 3. Informal. motivated by a sense of pity or sympathy for others or for oneself.
>
> /verb (used with object), pitied, pitying.
>
> 4. to feel pity or compassion for; be sorry for; commiserate with.
>
> /verb (used without object), pitied, pitying.
>
> 5. to have compassion; feel pity.
>
> /Idioms
>
> 6. have /take pity, to show mercy or compassion.

Though pity can be understood with mostly generous and compassionate connotations, unwelcomed and unwarranted pity can be destructive and often resented.